# Computing $\int_{\partial S} \frac{1}{1+z^n} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $S=\{re^{it} : 0<r<R, 0< \varphi < 2\pi/n\}$ for some $R>1$ and $n\geq 2$.

How can we compute $$\int_{\partial S} \frac{1}{1+z^n} dz?$$

I can't compute it directly, so I assume I should use Cauchy's integral formula, but I can't find a good way of applying it.

I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: Do you already know the residue theorem? [Integral formula works too, but it is slightly less obvious to see what to do with that.]

Comment: No, I'm not familiar w/ the residue theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply the integral formula, you need to write $\frac{1}{1+z^n}$ in the form

$$\frac{g(z)}{z-z_0},$$

where $z_0 \in S$ and $g$ is holomorphic on $S$ and continuous on $\overline{S}$. So we look for a zero of $1+z^n$ in $S$. The zeros of $1+z^n$ are

$$\zeta_k = \exp \biggl(\frac{(2k+1)\pi i}{n}\biggr),\quad 0 \leqslant k < n.$$

The only zero in $S$ is $\zeta_0$, and $$z^n + 1 = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (z - \zeta_k),$$

so with

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} (z-\zeta_k)}$$

we have

$$\int_{\partial S} \frac{dz}{1+z^n} = 2\pi i g(\zeta_0)$$

by the integral formula. Evaluating $g(\zeta_0)$ can be done more or less elegantly.

Comment: Thank you. I'm asked to prove $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx = \frac{\pi/n}{\sin(\pi/n)}$ using the above and letting $R\to \infty$, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. I've tried splitting the boundary into three paths and seeing what happens to each integral, but I get the wrong result. Can you tell me how to approach that?

Comment: The part of the contour on the circle $\lvert z\rvert = R$ is different from the parts on the straight lines. For the part on the circle, show that it tends to $0$ as $R\to\infty$, use the standard estimate (you may know it as the ML estimate or ML inequality, terminology differs). Then look at the parts on the straight lines. For the part on the real axis, it is immediate that it tends to $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n}\,dx$, isn't it? It remains to look at the part on the ray $\arg z = \frac{2\pi}{n}$.

Comment: Parametrising as $t\mapsto e^{2\pi i/n}\cdot t$ establishes a relation to the part on the real line, which you can use to obtain the desired result. You need to be careful with the signs, since the part on the ray $\arg z = \frac{2\pi}{n}$ is traversed towards $0$ as part of the boundary, and my parametrisation goes the other way.

Comment: Yes, I've tried something similar to what you're proposing. I get this: $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx = \frac{2\pi i g(\zeta_0)}{1-e^{2\pi i/n}}$$ but I don't know how to continue from there. It doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: I've just computed $g(\zeta_0) = -\frac{1}{n} e^{i\pi/n}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, $g(\zeta_0) = \frac{1}{p'(\zeta_0)}$, where $p(z) = 1+z^n$, so indeed $g(\zeta_0) = \frac{1}{n\zeta_0^{n-1}} = \frac{\zeta_0}{n\zeta_0^n} = -\frac{1}{n}\zeta_0$. So we arrive at $$\frac{2\pi i g(\zeta_0)}{1-e^{2\pi i/n}} = \frac{\pi}{n}\frac{2i e^{\pi i/n}}{e^{2\pi i/n}-1} = \frac{\pi}{n} \frac{2i}{e^{\pi i/n} - e^{-\pi i/n}} = \frac{\pi/n}{\sin \frac{\pi}{n}}.$$